# How do can I close all windows on Preview and OpenOffice, so they don't open again when I open Preview to see something else?

Tags: preview

Every time I view an image using Preview, it gets stored, and when I open preview again, everything is there, like this-
[image]

How can I clear that? 
Thanks

(for reference- I use Yosemite on a MacBook Pro)

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. Your question references clearing the items listed as recently opened, while the title of your question references not reopening windows which were open when a program was last closed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to prevent it happening again, remember to close a document before you Quit, otherwise it will reopen on launch.

To clear the existing list, With both apps quit, go to
`~/Library/Saved Application State/`

& delete the two saved state folders, `com.apple.Preview.savedState` & the same for OpenOffice [I don't have the app so not certain of the name.]

Done.

---

Quick way to get there, if you're not sure…

- From Finder, hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  for New Window
- Hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>  for Go…
- Paste `~/Library/Saved Application State/` including the tilde ~

Answer (score 0):

Even faster:

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>Space</kbd>
- `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState`
- *Delete contents*